# Need a Query to fetch distinct data from a table in my sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table History which contains below columns:

```
ID   Previous  Current  User     createdOn
1    RED       BLUE     System   2020-04-14 09:24:49.765000
2    GREEN     YELLOW   ADMIN    2020-04-12 03:56:34.765000
3    GREEN     BLUE     System   2020-04-14 11:37:21.765000
4    ORANGE    RED      System   2020-04-15 11:24:49.765000
```

I need a query to fetch data from a table in a manner that every user should return only one row for the day even if a user has more than one entry for a day

The required resultset should be as below :

```
User       CreatedOn
ADMIN      2020-04-12 03:56:34.765000
System     2020-04-14 09:24:49.765000
System     2020-04-15 11:24:49.765000
```

Comment: Can you please share the queries you have tried out so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by User and date and get the minimum `createdOn` for each user:

```
select User, min(createdOn) createdOn
from History
group by User, date(createdOn)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qDDefngghp6zgtyg3LSzyi/3).
Results:

```
| User   | createdOn                  |
| ------ | -------------------------- |
| ADMIN  | 2020-04-12 03:56:34.765000 |
| System | 2020-04-14 09:24:49.765000 |
| System | 2020-04-15 11:24:49.765000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the most recent record, for instance:

```
select h.*
from history h
where h.createdOn = (select max(h2.createdOn)
                     from history h2
                     where h2.user = h.user and
                           h2.createdOn >= date(h.createdOn) and
                           h2.createdOn < date(h.createdOn) + interval 1 day
                    );
```